# Searching the menu bar in Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows, productivity, search

I am looking for a program that can search for and activate application menu items for the frontmost application.

It should work on Microsoft Windows. Gratis is preferable.

On Mac OS X 10.10 I use  [Alfred 2](https://www.alfredapp.com/) + [Menu Bar Search](http://www.packal.org/workflow/menu-bar-search):

[image]

Comment: Hmm I don't this is possible because of the different ways Windows and Mac applications handle menu items. In Mac they have to "declare and set" the menu items, so they appear on the top bar, but in windows they stay inside the application, so it is very hard (maybe impossible?) to find a universal function that will show the menu items like the application you have on mac. If you are looking for an app to replace Alfred, I recommend Wox, but while it is very functional, it can't search and active menu items. It does have plugins though, so feel free to develop one for it! ;)

Comment: @CalvT Thanks for the recommendation, yes, unsure whether it can be done in Windows.